# PhpStorm terminal npm (node)

Tags: node.js, npm, phpstorm

I've just recently started using gulp.js in my projects and I've been trying to learn and use terminal a lot more.

When I run npm commands from the mac terminal default console everything works great however when I run the same commands in PhpStorm the command is not found.

I've followed PhpStorm's guides on installing and integrating the NodeJS plugin etc but I cant seem to get any of the commands to work through it even though its in my `usr/local/bin` and was installed globally etc.

When I SSH to vagrant though I can use the `npm` commands etc. Would anyone happen to be able to suggest anything?

Comment: Try launching PhpStorm from terminal like this `open -a /Applications/WebStorm.app/` instead of normal way (clicking on app icon in launcher). Any difference?

Comment: Morning LazyOne, thanks for your comment, that worked! Is there anyway i can give you credit for the answer with it being a comment?

Comment: If you are using `bash` as a shell -- have a look at [this comment](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5513463#5513463) (#4).

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite old but I came across the same problem.
What I did was enter the terminal settings under `tools > terminal`, go to Application Settings, and change the Shell path to the one you need.
Click the `...` button and select the one that suits you.
[image]